# Scrapy detect tag not closed

Tags: python, scrapy

The html page scraped have an sql error and I noticed the html tags are not even closed but my xpath selector can't detect anything inside the tag not closed.

How can i detect tags not close with scrapy ?

Thanks

Comment: Please add the error if any or your code and the website you are trying to scrap so that we can help.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a [mcve]. Use the "edit" link to improve your *question* - do not add more information via comments. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a lot of tools and libraries that try to fix broken html/xml content. However since scrapy is already using a `lxml` library for parsing we can also use it to fix the broken document:

```
from lxml import etree
from scrapy import Selector

def parse(self, response): 
    # lets pretend we have this unclosed <li> in our response
    print(response.body)
    #"<ul><li>foo</ul>"
    # create an lxml parser with recover parameter
    parser = etree.XMLParser(recover=True)

    # retrieve xml document 
    broken_body = etree.tostring(response.selector.root)
    clean_doc = etree.fromstring(broken_body, parser=parser)
    selector = Selector(root=clean_doc)
    selector.xpath("//li/text()").extract_first()
    # foo
```

Comment: Thanks you Granitosaurus !